# Installation issues using Ubuntu 13 CD endless load after connecting to WIFI

Tags: wireless, system-installation, internet

I was trying to install Ubuntu 13 and I had done a search on the CD and it said there were no defects and I could run ubuntu of the cd but when I went to install it was fine until it got to the bit where it asked for wifi. I entered it and it said I was connected on the right side but the installation took ages and made no progress what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your installation has failed resulting in corrupted file system.
U need to post further deatils like where there are other operating systems present, whether u r able to boot into them or is there a grub rescue mode,etc.

Comment: I have 2 versions of windows vista and a old laptop with a intel processor and 2 gigs of ram I'm trying to get ubuntu desktop 13.10 also I'm not good with computers and am downloading from cd but have tried USB.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04? 13.10? Ubunru Desktop or Server?

I had the same issue on 13.10 Server Installation using a USB install.

If this is the Case try Installing it from DVD without a Network connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly a driver issue. Try installing with an Ethernet cord plugged in. Or no connection at all, but Ethernet would be preferable. After the system is installed (or you could even try this from the liveCD) go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. There should be a proprietary driver you can enable to improve the performance of you wireless card.

Also, to help speed things up, don't install updates during installation.

Comment: I'm no computer whizz what's a live cd and would anything else help?